# Any element in categories Highcharts widget be a link

Tags: highcharts, hyperlink, yii2, widget

I have bar chart with Highcharts widget in yii2 project. I want to create hyperlink the category names so that clicking on the label (not the bar) loads the URL in a new window. How can do it?

In Highcharts used label in option but when I use that I get syntax error.

```
<?php
                $x = array("a", "b", "c");
                $y = array_values(array(4, 2, 6));
                echo Highcharts::widget([
                    'options' => [
                        'chart' => [
                            'type' => 'column',
                            'zoomType' => 'x',
                        ],
                        'title' => [
                            'text' => 'Project chart',
                        ],
                        'xAxis' => [
                            'categories' => $x, 
                        ],
                        'yAxis' => [
                            'title' => [
                                'text' => 'Count',
                            ],
                        ],
                        'series' => [
                            [
                                'type' => 'column',
                                'name' => 'p1',
                                'data' => $y,
                            ],
                        ],
                    ]
                ]);
                ?>
```

I want to each element in $x be a link.

Please tell me what I should do in the code that I posted because they are javascript code and I can't properly use my own code.

Comment: From Highcharts support site, I can only show you an example how to achieve it using JavaScript, but as I understood, you already have seen them... Maybe you should contact the yii2 Highcharts wrapper creators? https://www.highcharts.com/products/wrappers